# How do I access the storage of a restricted profile with adb on Android TV?

Tags: adb

I created a restricted profile on my Android TV running Android 9, tried to access the storage of the new profile but failed, here's what I got in adb shell (current profile for the TV is the restricted profile):

```
mytv:/sdcard $ cd /storage/emulated/10
mytv:/storage/emulated/10 $ ls
ls: .: Permission denied
1|mytv:/storage/emulated/10 $ whoami
shell
mytv:/storage/emulated/10 $ pm list users
Users:
    UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running
    UserInfo{10:Restricted Profile:18} running
mytv:/storage/emulated/10 $ am switch-user 10
mytv:/storage/emulated/10 $ ls
ls: .: Permission denied
1|mytv:/storage/emulated/10 $ whoami
shell
mytv:/storage/emulated/10 $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats),3009(readproc),3011(uhid) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

The device is not rooted and `su` command is not available.
So how do I access the storage of a restricted profile with adb on Android TV? TIA!

Comment: 1015(sdcard_rw) should be sufficient for storage, don't know why not working. Anyway, you can try [mtk-su](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit) (instead su)

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for the advice! However the TV box doesn't have a MTK chip so I guess mtk-su won't work on it.

Comment: shouldn't you be able to access via /sdcard while the desired profile is active?

Comment: yes I can access /sdcard, which is /storage/emulated/0, 
but I can't access /storage/emulated/10 in adb shell.

Comment: tought that depends on which userprofile is logged on and /sdcard automatically changes to /storage/emulated/10

Comment: Guess that's the case. 
So is it possible to switch logged in user in adb shell to any user other than `shell`?

Comment: the purpose of profiles is to separate spaces, guess the only way is log in and access the current user. not sure when that symlink is created but it will most likely point to the current profile, so switch the user (on gui as usual) and open separate adb session (if that is possible for other users than 0). please note i don't use profiles and what i write are just my thoughts, not valid knowledge